# Greatest-n-per-group; multiple ways of handling ties?

Tags: sql, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

Quite often I have to find a MAX/MIN value within a group. There are numerous solutions to this problem, but one thing they don't seem to account for is handling ties.

For example, take a dataset with the following records:

```
category   | product      | profit 2018  | profit 2017 | descr    
-------------------------------------------------------------
bicycles   | mountainbike | 10000        | 10000       |  ~~~~ 
bicycles   | blue bicycle | 12000        | 12000       |  ~~~~
bicycles   | unicycle     |  6500        |  7000       |  ~~~~
bicycles   | red bicycle  | 12000        | 14000       |  ~~~~
accessories| light        |  5000        |  3500       |  ~~~~
accessories| water bottle |  3200        |  2500       |  ~~~~
parts      | wheel        |  4000        |  4000       |  ~~~~
parts      | saddle       |  4000        |  3000       |  ~~~~
```

If I want to find the most profitable product over 2018 per category ([solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)), I'll get multiple rows per category because the blue and red bicycle are tied, and so are the wheel and saddle. Say I only want one result (for whatever reason).

I know of 2 ways to handle this:

1. Use ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...) and wrap the query in a CTE, then selecting WHERE ROW_NUMBER = 1. 
   What's nice about this solution is that I can use a tiebreaker in the order by, for example, I could use profit 2017 as a tiebreaker
2. Selecting Top 1. This solution just gives a random result?

Is there a better way of handling ties in a situation like this?

Comment: you can use also a max/min over partition

Comment: you could use an order by / tiebreaker also on solution n.2 - but the problem doesn't seem really technical but logical .. if there's a tie, which row you want to return?

Comment: How do you define "better way"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your table has some `identity` column. Then you can simplify the logic as :

```
select t.*
from table t
where identity_field = (select top (1) t1.identity_field 
                        from table t1
                        where t1.category = t.category
                        order by t1.profit_2018 desc
                       );
```